# join string and <cword> for vimgrep in command

Tags: vimrc, functions, vimgrep

I want to have a function that `vimgrep` for the word under the cursor appended to a predefined string.

I have defined this `command`:

`command! -nargs=0 GJL vimgrep <cword> *.tex | copen`

which does the job for only the current word. Now I want to grep for `ref{ + <cword>`. That is, in the case that `<cword>` is `eqn1`, I want to grep for `ref{eqn1`.

Any idea how to set up this function in a `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exec` with [string concatenation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-.):

```
command! -nargs=0 GJL exec 'vimgrep ref{'.expand('<cword>').' *.tex | copen'
```

In a function, you'd do something similar, but more neatly, I suppose:

```
function Foo()
    let l:pattern = 'ref{' . expand('<cword>')
    exec 'vimgrep' l:pattern '*.tex | copen'
endfunction
```

Comment: Works like a charm.